# Run a Task without killing

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement a functionality where user can simply click on download button and can go on any page that he/she wishes while download is still running, and it should not stop.

I'm using xamarin form.

Is there any way to do this, please suggest or any reference, since i couldn't find the same.

Comment: why would a task get cancelled just because you navigate to another page in your app?

Comment: It gets cancelled, when i press back button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the class `App` always exists in memory when the application is running , we can place the `Task` in `App`.

#### Simple Task

```
//App
 public async void DoSomething()
 {
    await Task.Delay(30000); 
 }

// in specific page
string result = await (App.Current as App).DoSomething();
```

#### Task with return values

```
//App
 public async Task<string> DoSomething()
 {
    await Task.Delay(30000);
    return "123";
 }

// in specific page
string result = await (App.Current as App).DoSomething();
```

---

If you don't want to put the code into `App` , we can create a extra class in `App` to handle this .

```
//App
 private MyTask _myTask;
 public MyTask myTask
 {
    get
    {
        return _myTask ?? new MyTask();         
    }
 }

//MyTask
public class MyTask
{
    public async Task<string> DoSomething()
    {
       await Task.Delay(30000);
       return "123";
    }
}

//in specific page
string result = await (App.Current as App).myTask.DoSomething();
```